# Is this one bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I prove that this one is bounded? $A_n+1=\frac1{3+A_n},\;\; A_1=1.$

I tried doing this: 
Suppose it's bounded from above by $1$ so $A_n\le1$ for every natural $n$.
for $A_1=1\le1$ it's true
suppose that it's true for $A_n\le1$,we have to prove it for $A_n+1$,so we get 
$A_n\le1  \iff  3+A_n\le4$  but now when I try using negative power we get $A_n+1\le\frac14$ so i get another value, can I count it as the value of bound from below?
I'm a little bit confused, can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Show by induction $0 \leq a_n \leq 3$

Answer (score 0):

$A_0=1$  Prove that $A_n>0$ (quite easy)

Then you have $A_n+1 = 1/(3+A_n) \le 1/3 $

$(A_n)$ bounded